# Mandolin Tuning Trouble

Tags: tuning, mandolin

I'm new to mandolins and I just got a mandolin that I'm trying to learn how to play. I was tuning it but the inside G string is too low, I tried turning the knob to make it higher to get to the right pitch but the knob is too tight to turn anymore unless I turn it the way to loosen it, but I need to tighten it. How do I get it so that I can keep tuning it higher?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Put some oil on the tuning machine (machine head) gears and loosen the string a bit. Step 2: Make sure that you're not an octave too high. If you're using an electronic tuner remember that they will often tell you a note is in tune, even when it's an octave out. Step 3: If you're sure you're in the correct octave, try tightening the string again.

Comment: step 4 put a a lighter gauge string on the mandolin.  Could be crappy strings or just too heavy for this mando